# Using pointers to copy values and divide number.

Tags: c, pointers

So I have three integer variables x, y and z and three pointers ptr1, ptr2 and ptr3.

The variable x has the value 4.

So what I want to do is using only pointers, copy the value x into y, divide x by 2, and then add it to y and then output the answer to z.

I have this so far ( just the basic) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    int y,z;

    int* ptr1;
    int* ptr2;
    int* ptr3;

}
```

Now how would I copy x into y.

I know I can copy x to ptr1 but doing something like:

```
ptr1 = &x;
```

Also dividing by 2. If I did this:

```
ptr1 = &x/2;
```

It gives me an error.

I'm new to C, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: No offence, you need a basic C book, this question is not fit here.

Comment: You must study something about pointers before start pushing keyboard buttons randomly...

Comment: The expression `&x/2` makes no sense, dividing an *address* (what a pointer really is) simply makes no sense.

Comment: "I know I can copy x to ptr1 but doing something like..." is not correct. You're not copying the value of `x` into that pointer.

Comment: @Kevin Jones, The &x/2 means divide the address of x by 2.

Comment: @SumeetSingh I though &x refers to the value at address of x

Comment: @KevinJones No *x when used in an assignment statement means that.

Comment: @KevinJones Its the basic by the way, there is plenty of online material to learn this stuff.

Comment: @KevinJones Absolutely right. Read my answer for more clarification

Comment: @SumeetSingh yeah i got it kinda, if I do ptr1 = &x and then z = *ptr1, it would print out 4

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Brian-W-Kernighan/dp/0131103628/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1461136729&sr=8-1&keywords=The+C+Programming+Language+K%26R) is worth every penny; get it.

Comment: _It gives me an error._ Would you be so kind and tell us which error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the value of x into y.You can do this using following:

```
ptr1 = &x;//ptr1 stores the address of x
ptr2 = &y;//ptr2 stores the address of y
```

Now copy it:

*ptr2 = *ptr1;

Let me break the above statement for you.

`*address` means value at the `address`. So `*ptr2` means value at the address of `y` is assigned `*ptr1`, the value at the address x.

Knowing this basic logic, you can write your program as:

```
ptr1 = &x;//ptr1 stores the address of x
ptr2 = &y;//ptr2 stores the address of y
*ptr2 = *ptr1;//copy x into y
*ptr1 = *ptr1/2;//divide x by 2
*ptr2 = *ptr2 + *ptr1;//add it to y
ptr3 = &z;//ptr3 stores the address of z
*ptr3=*ptr2;//output the result in z
```

Comment: how would I display the output, I try doing printf("%d", *ptr3); and a bunch of other method but doesn't work.

Comment: @KevinJones printf("%d",*ptr3); is correct.There should not be any problem. What error is it showing?

Comment: I get a different output. The output is "1820794936"

Comment: @KevinJones Are you sure you are following the exact sequence of statements which I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @KevinJones Please see my updated answer.

Comment: yeah I added *ptr2 = *ptr1; before the divide x by 2 and it worked

Comment: @KevinJones The reason was because we did not initialize y, it was picking garbage value for y.

Comment: @KevinJones The important point is to understand why the result was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
ptr1 = &x;
ptr2 = &y;
*ptr2 = *ptr1;
*ptr1 /= 2;
*ptr2 += *ptr1;
ptr3 = &z;
*ptr3 = *ptr2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start by making the pointer *point* to the variables.

```
int* ptr1 = &x;
int* ptr2 = &y;
int* ptr3 = &z;
```

This *does not* mean that you copy, e.g. x into ptr1. It means that ptr1 is *pointing to x*.

In order to use the pointers to change the value of the variable they point to, you need to dereference the pointer, i.e. use `*` operator.

```
*ptr2 = *ptr1;     // Same as y = x;
*ptr1 = *ptr1 / 2; // Same as x = x / 2;
// ... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, that &x is the address of x. So you basically tries to divide the memory-address if x by 2

if you want to do it, then ptr1=&x then ptr1/2